# How can i convert typescript callback to promise

Tags: mysql, typescript, promise

i want to make a method in my class. This method should connect to a MySQL database. I created my SQL code. And now I don't want to do a callback because this is old, I want to start using promises.

My function with callback (old school):

```
public does_player_exist(username: string, callback: any) {
    this.mysql.connect();
    this.mysql.query('USE devdb');
    this.mysql.query('SELECT p_name FROM players WHERE p_name = "'+username+'"', (err: Error, result: any[]) {
        if (result.length === 1) {
            callback(true)
        } else {
            callback(false);
        }
    });
}
```

And here follows the method I tried to make a promise, but I failed:

```
public does_player_exist(username: string): Promise<boolean> {
    this.mysql.connect();
    this.mysql.query('USE devdb');
    return this.mysql.query('SELECT p_name FROM players WHERE p_name = "'+username+'").toPromise().then((result) => {
        return result.length === 1;
    })
}
```

When I call this method:

```
service.does_player_exist('test').then((result) => { console.log(result) })
```

I hope someone can help me. Because I really don't want to be old school forever xD

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

create a  `new Promise` and resolve it / reject it in the callback functions of `query`. then return the promise. now `does_player_exist` returns a `Promise` object which contains for example `then` function

```
public does_player_exist(username: string, callback: any): Promise<boolean> {
    this.mysql.connect();
    this.mysql.query('USE devdb');
    var promise = new Promise<boolean>();
    this.mysql.query('SELECT p_name FROM players WHERE p_name = "'+username+'"', (err: Error, result: any[]) {
        if (!err) promise.resolve(!!result.length);            
        else promise.reject();
    });
    return promise;
}
```

you will have to make sure that you have a `Promise` class available. that depends on your environment.

please be aware that without sanitizing your input (username) your application will be vulnerable and attackers could hijack your app.

Answer (score 1):

Tip #1. Please use some kind of factory function to build your connection and reuse it later on.

Tip #2. Use [prepared statement](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) to prevent SQL injection.

Tip #3. Please use some promise library for that like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) or [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). Most of the 3rd party promise libraries have a lot of useful utility methods to work with promises on of them is promisify. Promisify can wrap any nodejs type callback function into function which returns a promise.
Your example would look like:

```
// it's not a factory function*
public query() {
    this.mysql.connect();
    this.mysql.query('USE devdb');

    return Promise.promisify(this.mysql.query.bind(this.mysql))
}

public does_player_exist(username: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return this
        .query('SELECT p_name FROM players WHERE p_name = ?', [username])
        .then(result => result.length === 1);
}
```

Comment: Promisify is a node built-in, you don't need an external library. `import { promisify } from 'util'`

Comment: True, now it is

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple npm package to do this in a way that retains type-safety:

[ts-promisify-callback](https://github.com/ChuckJonas/ts-promisify-callback)

It requires you use `typescript@^4.0` (upcoming release) and currently only works for callbacks in the popular format of `(err, result) => {}`.